# Can I push a portion of my git repository to a remote repository?

Tags: git, azure, workflow

I'm trying to figure out a workflow so that I can push to e.g. Windows Azure relatively easily. I have a Git repo as follows,

```
.git/
srcDir/
  -someFileThatShouldNotBeUploaded
deployDir/
  -someFileThatNeedsToBeDeployedToRootFolder
  -anotherFileThatNeedsToBeDeployedToRootFolder
```

I want to push just the `deployDir` as the root directory to a remote repo e.g. Azure.

I suspect this is possible using `subtree` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/199) almost gets there but it concentrates on transplanting a subdir into a separate repo thus removing it from the original. At also complicates things by using a branch which I'm not 100% sure is necessary ...

Comment: Pushing history is all-or-nothing. Hence, the only way to push a slice of the history (that contains only some of the files) is to create a filtered copy of the repository that doesn't contain the other files. I recommend using another method to deploy the files, e.g. something involving rsync. Of course that means you're not pushing to a remote repository but a remote directory of files...

Comment: I found that `git subtree push --prefix=deployDir origin master` actually works. On Azure it seems that the remote directory is a bare directory that runs a post commit checkout hook - this does not appea r to work for an ordinary repo though ...

Answer (score 1):

From a pure git standpoint, it's a bit tricky.

But from an Azure Web Site standpoint, you can choose what part of your repository actually gets deployed to the web site, by using a .deployment file at the root of your repo. See more info [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments).

In your case, the file will look like this:

```
[config]
project = deployDir
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using git unless you are very proficient.

Use standard file transmission protocols to transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a new repo in **deployDir** and run the push command from **deployDir**.

So you can versioning the releases the application.